# Building a path from strings in C

Tags: c, special-characters, filepath, strcat

I'm very new to C and am working on a utility that scans folders for duplicate files and then does some stuff to them.  When I have the list of duplicate file names, I need to build a string with the full path and file name to manipulate the files, but I get an error every time I try to append a \ to the path, but the error does not occur if I skip the .  Here is a simplified version of the problem code:

```
char *TARGET1 = ".";
char *TARGET2 = ".\\test"; 
char *PATH_SEP = '\\';

char *folder1_files[filecount1];  // These arrays are populated with file
char *folder2_files[filecount2];  // names elswhere in the code
int l = 0;  // The counter for the loop that is comparing the filenames

char buffer[1024];
strcpy(buffer, TARGET2);
printf("Building the path now...\n");
//strcat(buffer, PATH_SEP);
strcat(buffer, folder2_files[l]);
printf("Path: %s\n", buffer);
```

If I leave the third line from the bottom commented out, the program completes and I get the following output:

Path built!
Path: .\testfile3.txt

If I uncomment it, I get this error: Access violation reading location 0x0000005C

Can anyone point out where this is going wrong?  Is there a more standard way of building paths in C?

Comment: *names elswhere in the code* ... where? post that too. Use `snprintf()` instead that is easier and cleaner.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Note that `char *folder1_files[filecount/];` is a syntax error; did you mean `filecount1`?

Comment: third line from bottom is int l = 0 ; if you comment it, it would have generated compile time error at strcat(buffer, folder2_files[l]); with l undefined

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah yes... couple of typos in there.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character constants such as `PATH_SEP` are not automatically NUL-terminated. When you call

```
strcat(buffer, PATH_SEP);
```

the `strcat` routine expects both arguments to point to NUL-terminated strings. Because PATH_SEP isn't NUL terminated the routine continues scanning memory, looking for a NUL byte. Eventually it either overwrites something important or access memory it shouldn't.

Change

```
char *PATH_SEP = '\\';
```

to

```
char *PATH_SEP = "\\";
```

and your code should perform as expected.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I did not know that character constants would not be NUL terminated.  I changed char *PATH_SEP = '\\'; to "\\\0" and it did indeed work as expected!

Answer (score 1):

The third line from the bottom is

```
int l = 0;
```

If you comment it out, your code will not compile, because you need to declare `l` before using it.

The *fourth* line from the bottom is

```
//strcat(buffer, PATH_SEP);
```

The line

```
char *PATH_SEP = '\\';
```

makes no sense, because you initialize string (char*) with character (char).  Anything in double quotes is a string, anything in single quotes is a character.  So your PATH_SEP points to a garbage.